# More pythonic way to handle json response in Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, urllib2

I am currently using an API to return some JSON data with Python 2.7. My code is as below:

```
import urllib2

URL = "www.website.com/api/"
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
data = json.load(response)
my_variable = data['location']
```

I am just wondering if there is a more pythonistic way to assign an entry within the returned JSON data to my_variable. So, for example:-

```
my_variable = data['location'] in json.load(response)
```

or something similar to the above?

Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean `my_variable = json.load(response)['location']` ?

Answer (score 4):

You could, of course, shorten this to:

```
my_variable = json.load(response)['location']
```

but if you're going to extract more than just one value from that JSON, repeating `json.load` is inefficient and thus the variable `data` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise you could use the above syntax. Can you also embed the URL call into that line too?

Comment: Obviously; but it may make the debugging harder.